# Python: how to load json with dict containing range

Tags: python, json

my python code is about generating a sequence number from a dict keys, and my dict keys are defined with a range using `cycle` package in `itertools` module.

`working example:`

```
from itertools import cycle

e = {'Apple': cycle(range(1,999)),'Orange': cycle(range(1,999)),'Banana': cycle(range(1,999))}

def SequenceNum(f):
    return f'{next(e[f])}'.zfill(3)

X = SequenceNum('Apple')
print(X)
```

`output`

```
001 --> it keeps incrementing in the range specified above in dict `e`
```

`Challenge:`

My requirement is to convert this dict of `e` into a json file. So it will load keys and values by parsing json file.

`cat test.json`

```
{
    "DATA": {
        "Apple": "cycle(range(1,999))",
        "Orange": "cycle(range(1,999))",
        "Banana": "cycle(range(1,999))"
    }
}
```

(i had to put the dict values inside double quotes to avoid json file loading error.)

`code`

```
import json
from itertools import cycle

with open('test.json') as f:
    FromJson = json.load(f)
d = FromJson['DATA']
print(d)

def SequenceNum(f):
    return f'{next(d[f])}'.zfill(3)

X = SequenceNum('Apple')
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    print(i, SequenceNum('Apple'))
    i += 1
```

here new dict is `d` that loads json file and it will load the values in single quotes.

`output`

```
{'Apple': 'cycle(range(1,999))', 'Orange': 'cycle(range(1,999))', 'Banana': 'cycle(range(1,999))'} #THIS IS OUTPUT of 'd' after loading json file

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chandu\Documents\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(i, SequenceNum('Apple'))
  File "c:\Users\chandu\Documents\test.py", line 12, in SequenceNum
    return f'{next(d[f])}'.zfill(3)
TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

it is giving error because my dict values are not properly iterable by cycle itertools modules, since they are in quotes. i dont know if there is any other cause for this error.

please help to resolve this error,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you added quotes, but didn't even try to anything to undo that change?

Comment: Hi Scott, if i remove quotes on dict values in json file, it gives error at loading json file. May be it's against the json data formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure what each value is, you can do `eval` with care:

```
def SequenceNum(f):
    return f'{next(eval(d[f]))}'.zfill(3)
```

Note this is very dangerous to use, because `eval` evaluates anything that is passed into it and can cause harm.

---

This also will always fetch first value from iterator as it is evaluated new everytime. To solve, you can:

```
def SequenceNum(f):
    return eval(d[f])

i = 1
seq_iter = SequenceNum('Apple')
while i <= 10:
    print(i, f'{next(seq_iter)}'.zfill(3))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Hi Austin, thanks for your response..After using `eval`, iterator error got resolved.. But i am unable use cycle(range(1,999)) properly as it keeps printing 001 for every occurrence..

Comment: I have updated my question with a while loop at end. In working example, it prints 001, 002, 003..till 010... where as in json example (using eval) it keeps printing 001, and no increment to the value from its range.